# Webpage load times slow inside TestCafe Studio browser

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm experiencing some issue while running the test.
The results are inconsistent. Test passes and then fails couple of times and passes again. It looks like the reason is that page elements load very slow or at times not at all when running in TestCafe browsers via http://192.168.0.87:57745/hrj08_8ph

The same page accessed directly through the browser works absolutely fine and very snappy.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: The described behavior looks like a bug. I suggest you create a new issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).

Answer (score 0):

i sen a link use Set Test Speed before the test case you set first this after your site display fast as your setting

https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400173/test-actions/debug-actions

thank you

hope its work..